# magento 1.8 to set multi stores with single website, is it need to create multiple website

Tags: php, magento

I am creating multi store in single website in one magento 1.8 installation.
I gone through with many tutorials and documents for this. I have doubt that is it necessary to create multiple website also.??

http://www.inventcommerce.com/blogs/90-setting-up-multi-storefronts-on-magento

I want to do it in single main website. Is it possible.?
If I did it with multi website and single store for each and all are website are belongs to main website is it similler to my requirement???

Help me

Comment: Should be possible with 1.8, howeverever, you should move your question over to: http://magento.stackexchange.com/ , Stackoverflow is for programming questions, not for magento tutoring and support.

Answer (score -1):

You can create multiple stores with single website, follow the guidelines to understand the concept.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/overview-how-multiple-websites-stores-work